# How to change multiple elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, input, slice

Goal: User can choose a section of the list via list slicing to change to ' '

Example of list

```
list=['a','','','','','','','','','','b','','','','','','','','','','c','','','']
```

user can choose Start and End of list slice (start=0 and end=12)

```
start=input("Where to start? ")
end=input("Where to end? ")
```

What I tried:

```
list[int(start):int(end)]=['']
```

Excepted result everything from 0:12 is changed to ' '

```
['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','c','','','']
```

Actual result everything from 0:12 was removed from the list

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'c', '', '', '']
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work and why the code of line I tried doesn't work?

Comment: Think carefully about the code you wrote. What is it actually doing? It's taking a slice of the original list (BTW, don't use the names of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variable names) and replacing it with a single empty string. You didn't tell the interpreter to iterate over each item in the slice, so it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you shouldn't use keywords such as `list` for variable names.

Here you are replacing a large slice of your list with a single element so to fix this repeat the element for the same length of the slice.

```
start = int(start)
end = int(end)
my_list[start:end] = ['']*(end - start)
```

If you havent come across multiplying a list before it just repeats the elements that many times so for example `["a", "b"]*3 == ["a","b","a","b","a","b"]`

Comment: Ah thank you so much, had a feeling I needed some kind of loop or some way to repeat [' '] but couldn't think of a way to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to solve this issue.

```
i = start
while i =< end:
  list[i] = "whatever you want"
  i += 1
```